# Problem fetching data from inner join table with axios in react

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, field

I'm new in react so I'm trying to put the returning data from express with axios in fields, but i have some problems do display data from the join table.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FilmesDataService from "../services/filmes.service";

export default class Tutorial extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
        this.onChangeFoto = this.onChangeFoto.bind(this);
        this.onChangeGenero = this.onChangeGenero.bind(this);
        this.getTutorial = this.getTutorial.bind(this);
        this.updateTutorial = this.updateTutorial.bind(this);
        this.deleteTutorial = this.deleteTutorial.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            dataProduto: {},
            message: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getTutorial(this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    onChangeTitle(e) {
        const titulo = e.target.value;

        this.setState(function(prevState) {
            return {
                dataProduto: {
                    ...prevState.dataProduto,
                    titulo: titulo
                }
            };
        });
    }

    onChangeDescription(e) {
        const descricao = e.target.value;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            dataProduto: {
                ...prevState.dataProduto,
                descricao: descricao
            }
        }));
    }

    onChangeFoto(e) {
        const foto = e.target.value;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            dataProduto: {
                ...prevState.dataProduto,
                foto: foto
            }
        }));
    }

    onChangeGenero(e) {
        const generoId = e.target.value;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            dataProduto: {
                ...prevState.dataProduto,
                generoId: generoId
            }
        }));
    }

    getTutorial(id) {
        FilmesDataService.get(id)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    dataProduto: response.data
                });
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                alert(e);
            });
    }

    updateTutorial() {
        FilmesDataService.update(this.state.dataProduto.id, this.state.dataProduto)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.setState({
                    message: "Alterado com Sucesso!"
                });
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }

    deleteTutorial() {
        FilmesDataService.delete(this.state.dataProduto.id)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.props.history.push("/user");
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { dataProduto } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="edit-form">
                    <h4>Tutorial</h4>
                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                value={dataProduto.titulo}
                                onChange={this.onChangeTitle}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                value={dataProduto.descricao}
                                onChange={this.onChangeDescription}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="description">Foto</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                value={dataProduto.foto}
                                onChange={this.onChangeFoto}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputState">Género</label>
                            <select id="inputState" class="form-control" onChange={this.onChangeGenero}>
                                <option selected value={dataProduto.generoId}>
                                    {dataProduto.genero.name}
                                </option>
                                <option value="1">Drama</option>
                                <option value="2">Comédia</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <button className="badge badge-danger mr-2" onClick={this.deleteTutorial}>
                        Delete
                    </button>

                    <button type="submit" className="badge badge-success" onClick={this.updateTutorial}>
                        Update
                    </button>
                    <p>{this.state.message}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**filmes.service.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import authHeader from "./auth-header";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/";

class FilmesDataService {
    getAll() {
        // return axios.get("/trabalho");
        return axios.get(API_URL + "filmes/list", { headers: authHeader() });
    }

    get(id) {
        return axios.get(API_URL + `filmes/single/${id}`, { headers: authHeader() });
    }
}

export default new FilmesDataService();
```

**filmes.routes**

```
const { authJwt } = require("../middlewares");
const filmes = require("../controllers/filmes.controller.js");
const controller = require("../controllers/user.controller");

module.exports = app => {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });

    app.post("/api/filmes/create", [authJwt.verifyToken, authJwt.isAdmin], filmes.create);

    app.get("/api/filmes/list", filmes.findAll);

    app.get("/api/filmes/single/:id", filmes.findOne);
};
```

**filmes.controller.js**

```
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    Filmes.findByPk(id, { include: [Generos] })
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: "Ocorreu um erro a retirar os dados do produto com id=" + id
            });
        });
};
```

I just want put the value name of generos table on that field:
[image]

but when i try tu i got this error:
[image]

Comment: It seems like `dataProduto.genero` might not be what you expect it to be. Have you logged its value to see what it is?

Comment: dataProduto.genero is indeed an object (reading from the screenshot you posted of the response body)

Comment: when i write dataProduto.genero.name i got this error: i.imgur.com/scRkH2e.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's wrong. You are using an object in Option child, so it's not 
valid as React Child.
Alternative, you should change to:

```
<option selected value={dataProduto.genero.id}>{dataProduto.genero['id' or 'name']}</option>
```

It's should work.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, I got this error: https://i.imgur.com/lkRg6re.png

Comment: you can check undefined by `dataProduto?.genero?.name` or `dataProduto.genero ? dataProduto.genero.name : '---'`

Comment: dataProduto?.genero?.name  Works! =) ty

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to display dataProduto.genero which is an object and therefore not qualified to be rendered this way:

```
<option selected value={dataProduto.generoId}>{dataProduto.genero}</option>
```

You should do

```
<option selected value={dataProduto.generoId}>{dataProduto.genero.name}</option>
```

Comment: Got this error: https://i.imgur.com/scRkH2e.png when i do that! ty for your help

Comment: That error is correct indeed, as at the beginning of your component lifecycle or for missing "genero" properties that value would be undefined. You have to handle the situation, you could do a dataProduto.genero ? dataProduto.genero.name : "No name"